# IE9: not all borders are displayed

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-9, border

I am trying to create some tables for different pages. Right now the borders work for IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari, but not IE9. Just to let you  know, I created the borders in the table first then put in the background color.

Now here is a visual example of what is wrong with my code. I put Google Chrome and IE 9 right next to each other so you could see the borders working perfectly in a browser and how it is reacting in IE9. (Chrome on the left, IE9 on the right):

[image]

I'll looked in the Browser Developer Tools and the styles for the borders are there for both browsers, but the way IE9 reacts is very odd in my eyes, especially since the same code works fine for IE8.

**What I did for my code:**

For the borders, I have this:

```
table.policy_table td {
   border-top: 1px solid #A9B0B6;
}
```

So what I did to color in the rows is this in the PHP files for pages with the table. The reasoning with this is because I had to make sure browser compatibly worked from IE8 and up:

```
jQuery("tr:even").addClass("even");
```

and within the css file is this:

```
.even {
   background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

The reason I did not use nth-child is because IE8 will have access to these pages and IE8 does not support nth-child.
When I removed the background color code, all the borders are normal again.

**My questions:**

Do you think it is the way I tried to color in the background of the rows that messed up the borders? 
Does anyone know the reason why IE9 does this? I've been researching for a while now and found no results to why this occurred.

Comment: would it be possible for you to link to an example page?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that. Please check out http://jsfiddle.net/5SPVW/2/ ...

Comment: @MatthewThepc I'll try to put up an example page asap. To:Lars Once I am able to create an example page, that might be more helpful :)

Comment: you mention `nth-child` not working in IE8. have you tried [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)?

Comment: Maybe a browser zoom level issue?

Comment: @Justin - did you ever get an example page up? since it works fine with Lars' example, I've got a feeling it might be something in code you've not posted here.

Comment: The page suddenly worked again. I'm not sure what is the cause of it but now I am unable to reproduce the error. Thanks for the help though everyone!